# T/SQL - String Manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below query.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d474e/5)

I can only have possible 7 characters (- and A-Z combined)

There can only be ONE "-" for first 5 characters (Monday to Friday)
For Saturday and Sunday, we can only have one character or dash
 I am replacing Sa and Su with just S

However, whenever they are passing in TWO dashes for Saturday AND/OR Sunday, I need to replace them with ONE dash for each

so length can only be 7 after all manipulations.

I have tried w/e I could but getting stuck at the two vs one dash scenario for Saturday/Sunday position.

Please help! I will keep this updated as I find more.

THX in ADV

Code:

```
CREATE Table TempTable (string varchar(50))

INSERT INTO TempTable (string)
VALUES ('MTWRFSS')
       ,('MTWRFSaS')
       ,('MTWRFSaSu')
       ,('----F--')
       ,('----F----')
       ,('MT------')
       ,('MT------')
       ,('----FSa--')
       ,('----FSa-')
       ,('----FS--')
       ,('----FS-')
       ,('----F-Su')
       ,('----F--Su')
       ,('----F-S')
       ,('----F--S')

UPDATE TempTable
SET string =  REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(string)),'SA','S'),'SU','S')

SELECT string 
       ,LEN(String) AS stringLengh FROM TempTable

--DROP TABLE TempTable
```

Comment: Please post your code/problem here, do not make us go to another site to see it.  There's nothing wrong with giving us a SQLFiddle, but don't use it as a replacement for describing your code and problem here.

Comment: sry, I always post my code here but seen many people use SQLFiddle so I thought I would try that this time. :facepalm:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to manipulate only characters after 5th, because from MON to FRY you always have 1 -.
So I think this will work:

```
SELECT 
  string as InitialString
  ,LEFT(LEFT(String,5) + replace(replace(replace(RIGHT(String,LEN(String)-5),
  'Sa','S'),'Su','S'),'--','-') + '--',7) as FinalString
FROM TempTable;
```

You have to cut string into 2: left 5 and the rest. Then using several replaces you can have correct Sat/Sun combination. Concatenate both and you will have final decision.
Also 2 more dashes have to be added and the you have to take only `LEFT` 7, because if you have `'--'` it will be replaced with `'-'`.

Comment: This works as required. Thanks for the extra explanation too, your approach is very "ah-ha!" like...at least to me. :)

Comment: Yes, I enjoy your question :)